# Invalid factor level, NA generated (if-else statement won't work) in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am currently trying to solve an if-else problem.
I have one column in my data frame which contains numbers: the column is called "sentiment". I want to add a second column for which every row gets assigned a word: "positive", "negative", or "neutral". This column I call "evaluation". The criteria is that the column evaluation must hold the word "positive" if the sentiment column of that row contains a number above 0.25, "negative" if it holds a number below -0.25, and "neutral" otherwise. I tried running the following if-else construction:

[image: here's the code]

Subsequently, I would bind the evaluation vector with my existing data.frame, but that is not the issue, I know how to do that. But this statement generates "neutral" fine, but for every row that should be "positive" or "negative", an NA appears. I have no idea how to solve it. I am quite new to R, but am desperate for your help. "Invalid factor level, NA generated" is a warning I get. The problem does not seem to be in the fact that the column is not of a numeric type, because it is.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: this means that instead of TRUE or FALSE, your if logic is returning NA. To get around this, either remove the NAs or add a check like `if (!is.na(x) & x > 0.25)` or whatever you had

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you aware of R's vector functions or is there a specific requirement to use a `for` loop? Also, please note that growing a data object interatively is not recommended as this will become a performance issue when large objects are copied over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

M.,

I think your problem is related to `rbind`ing a character and a data.frame. Try this instead:

```
## I'm assuming reviews is a data.frame where column 9 is the sentiment data

sentiment = reviews[, 9]
evaluation = character()

for (i in 1:length(sentiment)) {
  if (sentiment[i] > .25) {
    evaluation[i] = 'positive'
  } else {
    if (sentiment[i] < -.25) {
      evaluation[i] = 'negative'
    } else {
      evaluation [i] = 'neutral'
    }
  }
}

reviews[['evaluation']] = evaluation
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to add an additional column `evaluation` with three factor levels which depends on the numeric values in the `sentiment` column.

This can be achieved without using a `for` loop through R's vector functions.

Unfortunately, the OP has not provided a sample dataset so we need to create this by

```
df <- data.frame(sentiment = c(-0.5, -0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5))
```

The `cut()` function can be used to convert numeric to factor. It divides the range of `x` into intervals and codes the values in `x` according to which interval they fall:

```
df$evaluation <- cut(df$sentiment, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.25, 0.25, Inf), 
                     labels = c("negative", "neutral", "postive"))
df
```

> ```
>   sentiment evaluation
> 1     -0.50   negative
> 2     -0.25   negative
> 3      0.00    neutral
> 4      0.25    neutral
> 5      0.50    postive
> ```

`cut()` uses *right closed intervals* by default. So, the edge case -0.25 is mapped to "negative". which is not fully compliant with OP's requirement and OP's code sample.

Alternatively, nested `ifelse()` calls can be used instead of `cut()`:

```
df$evaluation <- ifelse(df$sentiment < -0.25, "negative",
                        ifelse(df$sentiment > 0.25, "positive", "neutral"))
df
```

> ```
>   sentiment evaluation
> 1     -0.50   negative
> 2     -0.25    neutral
> 3      0.00    neutral
> 4      0.25    neutral
> 5      0.50   positive
> ```

This is now fully compliant with OP's requirement and OP's code sample which requires that -0.25 and 0.25 are mapped symmetrically to "neutral".

For the sake of completeness, there is also the `case_when()` function from the `dplyr` package which can be used to avoided the nested `ifelse()` calls:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(evaluation = case_when(
    sentiment < -0.25 ~ "negative",
    sentiment >  0.25 ~ "positive",
    TRUE ~ "neutral"
  ))
```

> ```
>   sentiment evaluation
> 1     -0.50   negative
> 2     -0.25    neutral
> 3      0.00    neutral
> 4      0.25    neutral
> 5      0.50   positive
> ```